# Do not Show Website With Bootstrap in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vuejs2

I'm using `Bootstrap` and `Vuejs` and `Laravel` on my web site .
 Every thing on chrome and firefox is ok , but when i use `IE` , blank page without any error displayed .
 When i disable bootstrap Css ( not bootstrap js) , every thing will be OK. I tested on IE 11 . 
I took a few photos of almost every part of the inspect element and console of IE  that I send to you.

[first part of inspect elment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqwlI.png)

[second part of inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUBKF.png)

[third part of inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqSSo.png)

[last part of inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKTKI.png)

[console IE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEty8.png)

Regards

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: This is the exact same question than someone asked hours ago. If you had no answer maybe it's because the way you ask is not good. Code is good, screenshots of code are bad.

Comment: I using bootstrap 3.3.7 but i change bootstrap version to 3.35 and 3.2.0 , Could not change

Comment: It is unlikely for bootstrap.css to hide the whole page content, even on IE.
Yet, you have given us no bootstrap version or the source code to inspect, so it's difficult to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a way cleaner solution but here's my input.

I have used `.disabled` property to disable `link` in Javascript.

The code first checks if you are using `IE` and disables accordingly.

Mess about with `link` index to find your `bootstrap.min.css`.

---

```js
// disables all styles in the document
function unloadStyleSheet(DOMelement) {
    DOMelement.disabled = true;
    DOMelement.parentNode.removeChild(DOMelement);
}

// Sample function that returns boolean in case the browser is Internet Explorer
function isIE() {
    ua = navigator.userAgent;
    // MSIE used to detect old browsers and Trident used to newer ones
    var is_ie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || ua.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;

    return is_ie;
}

// Disable CSS if IE
if (isIE()) {
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0]);
    unloadStyleSheet(document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0]);
} else {
  // Remove comments if you want to test in chrome
  //unloadStyleSheet(document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0]);
}
```

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid;
}

[class^='col-'] {
 border: 1px dashed;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">Hey</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">Hey</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">Hey</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">Hey</div>
    </div>
</div>
```